# How to bypass / Hack urandom value?

Tags: c, random

I have this C code and I want to know if possible how to bypass this check ?

```
int fd, password, input;
fd = open("/dev/urandom", 0);
read(fd, &password, 4);
scanf("%d", &input);

if (password == input)
{
    printf("OK\n")
}
```

Or is it possible to predict urandom values ?

Comment: You should use `O_RDONLY` rather than a hard-coded 0 in your second argument to `open()`.

Comment: What happens if `sizeof(int) != 4`?

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible to predict the values resulting from `/dev/urandom` on a properly-functioning system.

With that said, there is potential for error here:

- `/dev/urandom` could be created incorrectly, actually referring to e.g. `/dev/zero` or `/dev/null`
- There is no error handling in the code you've shown; a failure to open or read would go undetected, leaving the value of password unchanged.

Comment: Also, 32 bits is small enough to be cracked by simply guessing the same value repeatedly until it turns out to be correct.